# Microsoft Active Directory: Asking Tenant's Admin for Specific Permissions

Tags: azure-active-directory, office365, microsoft-graph-api

I have a Microsoft registered application.

I'm using the 'admin consent endpoint' in order to allow admins of organizations to consent to the permissions my app requires.

While I had a single organization using my app services, I had my permissions defined statically in my app page and it was working good.

Now I have multiple organizations and the permissions I need from each organization are different.

Is there a way for me to ask each tenant's admin for different permissions?

I know I can still define all of the permissions I need statically and always ask for all of them from each organization's admin, but I really rather not be asking permission I don't need and it can also deter those admins from giving their consent..

from looking in Microsoft docs I found this:

> The admin consent does not accept a scope parameter, so any permissions being requested must be statically defined in the application's registration. In general it is best practice to ensure that the permissions statically defined for a given application are a superset of the permissions that it will be requesting dynamically/incrementally.

So it seems like the answer to my question is 'no', but perhaps I'm missing something? It feels weird to not be able to ask only for the permission I need...

reference page:

[microsoft docs admin consent end permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-permissions-and-consent)

Answer (score 2):

Admin consented permissions must be defined in the application registration at this time. "Dynamic consent" is not supported for admin scoped permissions at this time.

Comment: I'd add that just because you've requested Admin Consent for a set of scopes doesn't mean you have to request User Consent for the same set of scopes.

Comment: Thank you both. I'm thinking now that perhaps I should have a Microsoft app for each different Microsoft app I'm integrating with, e.g Microsoft app for OneDrive (that will request OneDrive permissions) and different Microsoft app for Outlook (that will request mail permissions) and so I can request admins consents only for their relevant applications.. does that make sense?

Comment: @Noam sadly, that is what you have to do if you want to mimick dynamic consent with admin permissions. In our app we have a primary App Id with some permissions that everyone consents to and then another for some optional things.  its a PITA :)

Comment: @ChrisJohnson, ok, I did it and it seems to be working fine. thanks again :-)